# How to run code at startup, to mark all unread calendar items as read?

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I asked how to manually [mark all unread Calendar items in Outlook as read](https://superuser.com/questions/818797/outlook-2013-calendar-contacts-how-to-mark-all-as-read) on SuperUser.

I'd like to automate that with every startup of Outlook. It seems any time there is a new Calendar entry that is synced with Outlook, by default the entry is marked as unread.

I modified the VBA code to [mark all Outlook calendar items private](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/modify-all-calendar-items-private-using-vba-t1841318.html) with the [Outlook calendar unread property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862706(v=office.15).aspx).

How do I make this execute during the start up and for all my Calendars and sub-calendars?

```
Sub MakeAllRead()
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

On Error Resume Next

Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = oFolder.Items
For Each oAppt In oItems
    If Err Then
        Err.Clear
    Else
        oAppt.UnRead = False
        oAppt.Save
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Read/unread concept does not really apply to the calendar items. What exactly are you trying to do? Dismiss the reminders?

Comment: My first link refers to the manual steps of marking all Calendar items as read. The problem is that when new Calendar items are synced from elsewhere, it shows up as unread in Calendar. I want all Calendar items to be marked as read so they don't show up in the folder view. I am trained to act on folders with numbers, but in Calendars this type of count is not useful and counter to how I am trained to act on the folder.

Answer (score 1):

To run MakeAllRead at startup put this in ThisOutlookSession.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup() 

    MakeAllRead

End Sub
```

I would guess the calendar items would not be there before the code runs. You would then have to continue to run the code manually.

Refer to non-default calendars like this depending on where they are in the folder structure.

Application.Session.Folders("Calendar name")

Application.Session.Folders("Other mailbox name").Folders("Calendar name")

Application.Session.Folders("Other mailbox name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Calendar name")

Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Other calendar name")